# Why do I get different numbers of results from individual dates and date ranges when I query the Google Search Console API?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search-api

I'm using the API explorer on the side of [this page](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query).

When I query the API with this JSON

```
{
  "startDate": "2017-07-01",
  "endDate": "2017-07-01",
  "startRow": 0,
  "rowLimit": 5000,
  "dimensions": [
    "page",
    "device",
    "country",
    "date",
    "query"
  ]
}
```

I get a result with **4248** rows.

If I run this query again, but with both `startDate` and `endDate` as `2017-07-02`, I get **4355** rows.

Now, if I run it a third time with `startDate` as `2017-07-01` and `endDate` as `2017-07-02`, I only get **3947** rows.

I would expect that since I have `date` included in `dimensions`, that the two dates wouldn't interfere with one another, and I would get back 4248 + 4355 =  8603 rows. What's going on here?

Comment: Set dimension to only page and run the query again. I think you're getting different result because you've set some dimension.  If you analysis all three reports raw, then you'll get idea yourself how dimension works. I have not personally used my self search console API, so I can't say more.

Comment: Do you get the same numbers from within Search Console without the api?

Comment: @Kristian It's hard to say. Search Console limits you to 999 results; the API does not seem to have a limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was assuming that when I got fewer than **5000** rows in my results, then I had grabbed all available data.

However, the API often returns fewer than **5000** rows even if your `row limit` is set to **5000**. I found that when I continued to increment `startRow` until there were **no** rows in my results, then the numbers added up properly.